# How to rewrite the name of key of object in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object like this

[image]

What I want to do is show count at specific time.
For now, I have this code and it works fine

```
  <mat-card *ngFor="let room of roomList; let i = index">
    <mat-card-content>
      <h3>Room Number: {{room.staticData.rName}}</h3>
      <p>{{room.occupation[0].timetable.at17.count}}</p>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

What I would like to do is to rewrite the line in the p tag `room.occupation[0].timetable.at17.count`, because `at17` is hardcoded right now.

I want to assign variable in my component, a value of variable `hour` I become from server (it works too) and then I concat it to "at" and assign the whole to `this.time`

```
this.time = 'at'++this.hour;
```

So, would I would like to have is

```
      <p>{{room.occupation[0].timetable.time.count}}</p>
```

But it doesn't work...
How could I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using it as below,

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let room of roomList; let i = index">
    <mat-card-content>
      <h3>Room Number: {{room.staticData.rName}}</h3>
      <p>{{room.occupation[0].timetable['at'+i].count}}</p>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be `timetable['at'+i].count`? with the dot removed between `timetable` and the `[]`

Comment: @AnnaF check the updated answer I misplaced a `.` @QuiteOran pointed out correctly

Comment: @AnnaF happy to help you. mark answer and upvote too :)